# Initialize a random sequence that is the same each time you then refer to it in F#

Tags: f#, random

I was looking to take a random sample from a sequence by zipping it to a random infinite sequence and doing quickselect on the second element of tuples, but I hit the problem that a sequence initialized with random integers doesn't stay with the same value from the first time it was evaluated. So for example the following code outputs 5 different lines.

```
let ran=new System.Random(10001100)
let MySeq=Seq.init 10 (fun i->ran.Next())
for time in 0..4 do (for element in MySeq do printf "%s " (element.ToString()) 
                     do printf "\n")
```

Is there any way to initialize a sequence with random values so that the values remain constant once evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a hard dependency on `mySeq` really being a lazy sequence, you can just make it an array instead.

```
let ran = System.Random(10001100)
let mySeq = Array.init 10 (fun i -> ran.Next())
for time in 0..4 do
    for element in mySeq do
        printf "%O " element 
    printf "\n"
```

Comment: This definitely seems the thing to do. The quickselect runs a lot faster on arrays that cached sequences anyway. Thanks